# Diferença do Build de produção e desenvolvimento no Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Gostaria de saber quais as diferenças do `build` de produção e o `build` de desenvolvimento no `Angular`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Desenvolvimento

```
ng build
```

ou

```
ng build --dev
```

- São gerados arquivos "maps", arquivos com a extensão .js.map
- O código não é minificado e uglification
- Não faz um "Tree shaking", onde é limpo o "código morto"
- Não há compilação AOT

> Utiliza a configuração do arquivo environment.ts

## Produção

```
ng build --prod
```

- Não são gerados arquivos "maps", arquivos com a extensão .js.map
- O código é minificado e uglification
- Faz um "Tree shaking", onde é limpo o "código morto"
- Há compilação AOT

> Utiliza a configuração do arquivo environment.prod.ts

**Uglification** - Coloca nomes curtos para as variáveis

**Minificado** - Processo de remoção de espaços em brancos, comentários e qualquer código desnecessário para que a maquina interprete

**Tree shaking** - Processo para remover qualquer código que não tem utilidade para a aplicação

## Fontes

[Angular Dev Build vs Prod Build](https://sites.google.com/site/debasish22blog/angular-dev-build-vs-prod-build)

[Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

[AOT](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compila%C3%A7%C3%A3o_AOT)

[How to manage different environments with Angular CLI?](https://blog.angulartraining.com/how-to-manage-different-environments-with-angular-cli-883c26e99d15)